# using applet with several classes

Tags: java, tomcat, applet, classpath, japplet

I’m a newbie with applets so please be patient with me.

I have a japplet class that uses a several classes and I want to run it from the browser.
I'm using Tomcat to run the applet, I can't find away to link the other classes to the Japplet class.

Where to put the other classes? or any other idea that will help me solve this problem.

my HTML

```
<html>
<title>Test Applet</title>
<hr>
<applet class="Main.class" width="320" height="120">
</applet>
<hr>
</html>
```

My applet class:

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import com.getSlide.MainApp;

public class Main extends JApplet {

    public void init() {
        System.out.println("init");
        MainApp main = new MainApp();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: :) it's not my teacher, I need to develop an application the uses location and i can't do that with java application because Windows OS doesn't provide geo-location service.

Comment: *" I need to develop an application the uses location and i can't do that with java application because Windows OS doesn't provide geo-location service."*  Almost ***anything*** that can be done in an applet can also be done in an application.  Having said that, I'm not quite sure why you think that series of words rules out a desktop (or command line) app.

Comment: I've searched the web and didn't find a solution for this, one of the solution is to install a sensor but i don't like this solution.
do you know how can i obtain geolocation from java application?

Comment: *"do you know how can i obtain geolocation from java application?"* How do you do it from an applet?

Comment: *"using javascript "*  Ouch!  OK - glad I qualified that comment with 'almost', because 'interacting with JS' is one thing that a desktop app. cannot do, or rather, it does very poorly at unless you put a lot of work into using the `ScriptEngine`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where to put the other classes?

That depends on what package they are in.  If they are in the default pack like the `Main` (as `class="Main.class"` implies), the same directory.

OTOH it is better to put the classes into a Jar.

> How can I call the jar from the applet?

Presuming the Jar is called `the.jar`..

```html
<html>
<title>Test Applet</title>
<hr>
<applet code="Main" archive="the.jar" width="320" height="120">
</applet>
<hr>
</html>
```

Note also that:

```
class="Main.class"
```

Should be:

```
code="Main"
```

Comment: how can i call the jar from the applet?

Comment: thanks, apparently i have another problem NoClassDefFoundError I'll try to solve it, many thanks